# Bars are not centered in d3.js x-axis

Tags: d3.js, axis, bar-chart

I have a barchart, where the x-axis displays the weekday and the day of the month.
I have a little problem, that the values of the x-axis are not in the center of the bar like it is in the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304:

[image]

This is what mine looks like:

[image]

some code snippets:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width], .1);
var d3ticks = d3.time.days;
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(d3ticks, 1)
    .tickFormat(format)
    .orient("bottom");
svgGroup.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
```

What do I miss?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the number of bars and ticks is different. Make sure that they're the same if you want them to align.

Comment: plz put code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a long time to get the fiddle-sample running. But here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/axman/9N3FP/8/